# Set a variable as content for qtip content within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, qtip2

i am using this:

```
    // Built title error
    function showUsernameError() {
    $('.addbuildtitle').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
    // Show error qTip
    $('#addbuildtitle').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Please enter a build title'
    },
    show: '',
    style: {
    classes: 'qtip-red qtip-shadow'
    },
    position: {
    my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
    at: 'bottom center', // at the bottom right of...
    target: $('#addbuildtitle') // my target
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'unfocus'
    }
    }).qtip('show');
    }
```

What i currently do is this in my ajax call:

```
    if (response.emptyTitle === true) {
        showUsernameError();
    }
```

Which works, however there can be multiple error messages.

I want to try and set the qTip content text in the ajax response.

I have tried:

```
    if (response.emptyTitle === true) {
        var errorMessage = 'Test';
        showUsernameError();
    }
```

And then set the function to:

```
// Built title error
function showUsernameError() {
    $('.addbuildtitle').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
    $('#addbuildtitle').qtip({
    content: {
        text: errorMessage
    },
    show: '',
    style: {
    classes: 'qtip-red qtip-shadow'
    },
    position: {
    my: 'top center',  // Position my top left...
    at: 'bottom center', // at the bottom right of...
    target: $('#addbuildtitle') // my target
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'unfocus'
    }
    }).qtip('show');
}
```

But that doesnt work, this is just my lack of js knowledge. I am sure its simple to do i just cant figure out.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Does showUsenameError have access to the errorMessage var? Add a breakpoint and see what errorMessage is assigned as on showUsernameError

Comment: The var is setting right, but i have got an undefined errorMessage. Should i be declaring something in the function?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to pass an argument into my function e.g.

```
function showTitleError(errorMessage) {
    $('.addbuildtitle').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
    $('#addbuildtitle').qtip({
        content: { text: errorMessage },
        show: '',
        style: { classes: 'qtip-red qtip-shadow' },
        position: { my: 'top center', at: 'bottom center', target: $('#addbuildtitle') },
        hide: { event: 'unfocus' }
    }).qtip('show');
}
```

And then when calling the function do:

```
errorMessage = 'My Error Message';
showTitleError(errorMessage);
```